# What is that「かオイ」sentence ending?

Tags: colloquial-language, manga

I found few instances of「プール行くかオイ」in the manga I'm reading like this one below.

[image: q]

It seems to means「プール行こう」but I don't understand the purpose of「かオイ」sentence ending. I thought at first that this オイ is an injection meaning "hey" but I don't think it makes sense in this context. The speaker of this phrase is a woman and it's weird to me that it is placed at the end of the sentence, not the beginning.

Is「かオイ」some kind of slang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only the ending [か](https://www.kokugobunpou.com/%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E/%E4%B8%BB%E3%81%AA%E7%B5%82%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E%E3%81%AE%E7%94%A8%E6%B3%95/#gsc.tab=0) + オイ ("Hey!"). With  オイ, it sounds like the speaker demanding the listener's attention/response.

This sounds rude, and in that sense, can be called a slang. Depending on contexts, it can mean hostility.

Note that オイ is not a grammatical ending. It is just *Hey*. `プール行くかオイ : Are we going to a pool, aren't we?`
can be written `プール行くか、オイ` or `オイ、プール行くか`.

The fact that this is said by a woman or a girl is not that surprising. I think that  'strong' girls often talk that way in manga, even though very few girls (and possibly no women of decent age...) would do so in reality.

===

A particular phrase that comes to my mind is `やんのかオイ`, which means something like *Are you gonna fight with me?*. This オイ can be replaced with コラ (`やんのかコラ`). These are typically used by naughty boys (不良) in manga confronting with each other.